# How set server name in htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf

Trying to fix error in website i get:

```
The 'server' header should only contain the server name.
```

It becouse return:

```
Server: apache/2.4.46
```

I need to have only:

```
Server: apache
```

Looking on:

```
https://webhint.io/docs/user-guide/hints/hint-no-disallowed-headers/?source=devtools
```

I have added in my `htaccess` (`headers.c` is enabled):

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset Expires
    Header unset Host
    Header unset P3P
    Header unset Pragma
    Header unset Public-Key-Pins
    Header unset Public-Key-Pins-Report-Only
    Header unset Via
    Header unset X-AspNet-Version
    Header unset X-AspNetMvc-version
    Header unset X-Frame-Options
    Header unset X-Powered-By
    Header unset X-Runtime
    Header unset X-Version
</IfModule>
```

But it not solved the problem. I read too about:

```
ServerTokens Prod
```

But this work only in `httpd.conf` and not in `htaccess`.

So, the question is: how i can solve it and set only name of server without version?

Comment: Not sure if Apache allows you to unset that header. There might be no other way, than to do this via the actual server configuration. Question is though, _why_ would you need this in the first place? (You have read the note at the end of https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servertokens explaining that this doesn’t really “increase security”, yes?)

Comment: @CBroe sincerly was for not display it as "error" when user check in analysis from browser. I trying to have 100% on all (performance, accessibility, seo, best practise and pwa) and not like display: "some error detected". Working hard for it, i try to have something as: "no errors found." :D It is just a personal challenge.